# Json RPC error 32600

Tags: json, json-rpc

I am using jquery ajax to pass json rpc request to remote server. Here is my json string:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"merchant_check","params":{"hostID":150999,"orderID":107,"amount":"7777","currency":"051","mid":15001038,"tid":15531038,"mtpass":"12345","trxnDetails":""},"id":107}
```

I am getting this error:

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":null,"error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Invalid JSON-RPC 2.0 request error (-32600)"}}`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help.

Comment: What service is this being sent to? Some like [value] and others like {param:value}. Does it definitely accept JSON-RPC v2.0? Does the service expect authentication parameters to be in the JSON-RPC envelope? Otherwise, it looks OK to me.

Comment: It is being sent to payment system. Srever definitly accepts json-rpc 2.0 requests. The list of parameters is correct. 32600 error means Procedure Call with invalid JSON-RPC. So I think there is something wrong with my syntax.

Comment: I don't :-) The spec is here: http://jsonrpc.org/specification

Comment: Are you perhaps sending some unicode character that _looks_ like syntactic punctuation, but is not?

Comment: I have tried some online json validators and they all say that my string is valid.

Comment: Well, it's valid then. However, something else is expected by this particular webservice.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the JSON liberary the service is using. Try the following:

1. Put spaces between the end of a key string+colon amd tje value, "key": "value" vs "key":"value"
2. Try putting the request id as a string, "id": "1" vs "id": 1
3. I don't know how well ist was coded, the service, but if you have malformed parameters, it may give you the-32600 error, instead of -32602. So what kind of currency are you using that requires no decimal and gets sent as  string? What is a "mid", an integer?

Your request object looks good, it think it's what the service is expecting and calling good or bad request object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using json-rpc net. The problem was caused by the `content-type` header. By default it was being set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by my browser and it generated that error. Setting it to `application/json` fixed my issue.