# Json RPC request via jquery getJSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, getjson, json-rpc

I am trying to send json-rpc request to remote server with jquery getJSON method. Here is my code:

```
json_string=JSON.stringify(obj);
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("https://91.199.226.106/ssljson.php?jsoncallback=?", json_string, function(data){
    alert("aaaaaa");
});
jqxhr.error(function() { alert("error"); })
```

Here is my json-rpc string example:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"merchant_check","params":[{"hostID":150999,"orderID":116,"amount":"150","currency":"051","mid":15001038,"tid":15531038,"mtpass":"12345","trxnDetails":""}],"id":116}
```

And here is the error I get:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":null,"error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Invalid JSON-RPC 2.0 request error (-32600)"}}
```

I can`t get what is the issue. Am I doing something wrong? Maybe I need to send request with php and not jquery? Then how should I do it?

Comment: Any reason you've asked this question without closing/re-writing your other (duplicate) questions here:`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988733/json-rpc-error-32600` and here:`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871972/json-rpc-string`

Comment: Added jQuery tag, removed JSONP tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getJSON` as the name say will send `GET` request if you want to use JSON-RPC you need to use POST like:

```
var json_string = JSON.stringify(obj);
$.post('https://91.199.226.106/ssljson.php', json_string, function(response) {
   // process response
}, 'json');
```

but this will only work if your page is on the same server, unless you use CORS.

Answer (score 0):

That specific error message is *supposed* to tell you that the message envelope is invalid per the JSON-RPC 2.0 spec, or that there's a parse error in the JSON itself.

Unfortunately, in practice, many services return this error under a much wider variety of circumstances. (e.g.: missing authentication token, etc)

**Specific problems with your example message?**

Does the web-service accept `GET` requests? (i.e: should this be a `POST` instead?)

Does the web-service actually require the `?jsoncallback=?` bit? That's normally for a  JSONP request rather than JSON-RPC. The service is returning a real JSON-RPC error status, so I'd be really surprised if it needed that GET parameter, and (depending on the web-service configuration) might be interpreted as part of the envelope, which would make it an invalid JSON-RPC request!

Does `merchant_check` take an array of one-or-more transactions as its only parameter? If not, then you've got the syntax wrong for `params`. Some services want `params` to be an `Array`, some services want it to be an `Object`. Consult the SMD/documentation to determine which is the case.

The service might require `text/json` (or something else) as the `mime-type` for the request.

**Recommended Approach**:

To avoid these issues, you should probably start by using a purpose-built JSON-RPC library, like the one provided in Dojo toolkit, and use the SMD published by the web-service if it has one. (I recommend against hand-constructing JSON-RPC messages).